# Updating database using form tag

Tags: forms, struts2, user-input

I am using Struts 2, I am using form tag to capture the user input and update the database.
After updating, I should stay on the same page.

What should be the return type for struts.xml?

Answer (score 1):

If your page name is `editUser.jsp` than you must give it in success of action in struts.xml

```
<action name="update-user" method="execute" class="yourPackageName.yourActionClassName">
    <result name="success">/editUser.jsp</result>
</action>
```

update-user is action that you may set in form tag's action attribute.

In yourAction.java

```
public String execute() {
    //code for update
    return "success";
}
```

If you  are loading form data from another action than in struts.xml you have to specify that action's name. For example if the action to load data to display in form textfields is loadUserForm.action than after update the same page should be rendered with updated values. In struts.xml

```
 <action name="update-user" method="execute" class="yourPackageName.yourActionClassName">
    <result type="redirectAction" >load-user-form</result>
</action>
```

And this load-user-form will have

```
<action name="load-user-form" method="execute" class="yourPackageName.yourLoadingUserdataActionClassname">
    <result name="success">/editUser.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Comment: Thanks trivedi. But my problem is something specific. Like I am traversing to the particular page with several navigation of action. And I landed on a popup. where the user can enter some comments and post on it. the comments should be updated in backend and I need to get a popup saying comment posted. and popup should be closed. I can't specify the action to be redirected, it can be action...